# Strange issue with the right side margin

Tags: margins, article

I am not sure why the margin on the right side of my document is unusually larger than usual. I am presenting an MWE where I have (unsuccessfully) tried to resolve the issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=red,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor=gray]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{[#1]}}
\oddsidemargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in
\title{Assignment1}
\author{Joe Schmoe}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Question 1}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you used `\oddsidemargin=1in`. You should not manipulate those settings directly. Use `\usepackage{geometry}` with appropiate settings. Off-topic here: `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `oneside` default option in `article`, `\evensidemargin` is never considered. Contrary to what you may think, it doesn't set the right margin, but only states what's the *left* margin on even numbered pages when the printing is `twoside`.

By saying `\oddsidemargin=0in`, you're telling LaTeX that the text starts one inch from the left border of the page. Yes, really! Such parameters are best dealt with by experienced users. Note that you're not setting `\textwidth` so the default value is used.

You don't tell what your aim is, but if it is to have one inch on either margin, it's much simpler to call `geometry`:

```
\usepackage[
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
]{geometry}
```

Remove the settings to `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`.